# Where do I run logcat from?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, adb, logcat

I am using Xamarin and my Google Maps application is not showing the map. I am wanting to check the logcat output to resolve this situation.

How can I check the logcat output? I have done some research and I need to use the following command: "adb logcat -d -v time > logfile.txt"

But where do I run this statement from? Is it from the command prompt or from in Xamarin, or somewhere else?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have browsed to the platform-tools folder in the android sdk folder and have run the following command: "adb logcat -d -v time > logfile.txt"

The output says: "waiting for device"

When do I run the "adb logcat -d -v time > logfile.txt" command? Do I run it while the app is running in Xamarin or after, or sometime else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to go to your `androidsdk` folder, then `platform-tools`, then you will find `adb`. On my mac, I have to do this : `cd` to come back to the home folder, then `cd androidsdk/plateform-tools`, then `./adb logcat`.

Comment: @user22707 "waiting for device" means you did not plug in any device or the computer does not recognize your mobile device. If you plug in your device with the USB cable, you then start logcat.If it says "waiting for device", you'll have to look for the why your device is not recognized.

Comment: Thanks. I have got it working. I am using an emulator.